# autovivify non-sequential array/list in Python like Perl

Tags: python, arrays, list, perl

In perl I can have what I think are called sparse arrays.

```
my @a;
$a[4321] = "blah";
```

and it just does what I want. I don't know how to do this in Python without an error `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. What is the (simplest) way to do this in Python?

Comment: In Python, you'd probably want a dictionary - the keys are not required to have any relationship to each other.

Comment: Perl arrays aren't sparse, but as you note they do auto-extend on assignment.  You could do [something similar in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544630/automatically-growing-lists-in-python), but it's not a pythonic thing to do.

Comment: @jasonharper if I used a dictionary I'd need to sort the keys numerically afterwards. Hmm.

Comment: @craigb I'm not a pythonic person, but I can live with being unnecessarily C-ish. I was hoping to avoid exactly that approach though.

Comment: That array is not sparse. It has 4322 elements.

Comment: @Lucky I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749640/482519

Answer (score 1):

That array is not sparse. It has 4322 elements.

In Python, the following would create a similar construct:

```py
a = [ None for i in range( 4321 ) ] + [ "blah" ]
```

If you want to set an element of an array that might be beyond the end of an existing array, [@OmnipotentEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483486/omnipotententity) [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69183382/589924) this function.

```py
def set_at( xs, idx, x, default=None ):
   if len( xs ) <= idx:
      xs.extend( [ default ] * ( idx - len( xs ) + 1 ) )
   xs[ idx ] = x

a = [ ]
set_at( a, 4321, "blah" )
```

If you truly want something sparse, you can use a dictionary with integer keys.

```py
a = { }
a[ 4321 ] = "blah"
```

Comment: My Python knowledge is limited. Let me know if there's a better way.

Comment: I think that is pythonic, but that would clobber any elements I sprinkled in prior to 4321. In perl I can just do `$a[1234] = "blah"; $a[4321] ="foo"` without wiping the value at 1234.

Comment: Re "*but that would clobber any elements I sprinkled in prior to 4321*", I was adding an solution to that as you posted your comment :) See update.